# Yet another vowel counting program

Tags: beginner, ruby, iteration

Several months ago, I asked [*Program to count vowels*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144074/program-to-count-vowels), which was asking for a code review of a vowel counting function in implemented in Python.

Since I've been trying to learn Ruby, I decided to reimplement the entire program in it. I'm mainly looking for critiques on:

- Naming conventions
- Best practices for string iteration
- `do/end` vs `{}`
- Coding standards and best practices

Of course there are some slight changes in how I implemented this in ruby vs Python. The biggest being simply using a `Hash` since I couldn't find a suitable replacement for Python's tuples. On a unrelated side note, is there a replacement for Python's tuples in ruby?

---

```
def count_vowels(string)
    # Create a function that will receive a string. The
    # function will count each vowel in the string and
    # return a count of all the vowels, whether found or not,
    # each being a `key, value` in a Hash.
    vowels = {"a" => 0, "e" => 0, "i" => 0, "o" => 0, "u" => 0}
    string.each_char do |chr|
        if vowels.has_key?(chr)
            vowels[chr] += 1
        end
    end
    return vowels
end
```

Comment: How would you implement this in Python using tuples?! I'd just use `collections.Counter`. Which is pretty much the same as what you're doing.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Yes, I know very well that`collections.Counter()` is the "proper" way to go about something such as this.  I created that program for practice only. If I ever had to do something like this for production level code, I'd use the python standard library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`Enumerable#count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count):

```
string.chars.count { |char| vowels.has_key?(char) }
```

You very rarely need to declare a variable (`i` in this case), and then modify it form inside a block; there's almost always a better way in Ruby.

So while calling `count` and passing a block is the most direct, you could also have done something like:

```
string.chars.select { |char| vowels.has_key?(char) }.count
```

Same idea, just written out in separate filter/count steps.

You can also skip the `return` since that's implied at the end of a method.

I'd also use a plain array for the vowels. Looking up hash keys is faster, sure, but does it *really* matter that much? Nah. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" and all that.

```
vowels = %w(a e i o u) # same as ["a", "e", "i", ...]
```

and then the block becomes:

```
vowels.include?(char)
```

If you keep the vowels array sorted, you can use `bsearch` if you want to speed it up a little. Or you can construct the hash in code, instead of typing all that `=> 0`:

```
list = %w(a e i o u)
vowels = Hash[list.zip(list)] # => { "a" => "a", "e" => "e", ... }
```

---

Of course you could also do something funky like this: Remove all the vowels and see how much shorter the string is afterward:

```
def count_vowels(string)
  string.length - string.gsub(/[aeiou]/, '').length
end
```

This is also easily made case-insensitive:

```
string.length - string.gsub(/[aeiou]/i, '').length
```

Or instead of `gsub` you can use `tr`:

```
string.length - string.tr('aeiou', '').length
```

(or `'aeiouAEIOU'` for case-insensitivity.)

---

Alternatively, you could extend/monkey-patch the `String` class a little. I wouldn't recommend it for production code, though. This is just illustrate some Ruby features:

```
class String
  def vowel?
    self =~ /\A[aeiou]\z/ ? true : false
  end
end

def count_vowels(string)
  string.chars.count(&:vowel?)
end
```

The `&x` syntax is a shorthand meaning "invoke `x` on each element in the collection", so it's equivalent to `{ |e| e.x }`.

Again, this is mostly for fun. I just thought it made the `count_vowels` method nice and short. And of course, `count_vowels` could itself be monkey-patched onto `String`, so you could just call `some_string.count_vowels`. But again, monkey-patching - while fun - shouldn't be the first thing you reach for. Just illustrating the principle.

Comment: Also `s.chars.grep(/[aeiou]/).size` is a short way to accomplish the same thing

Comment: Another shorter way is `str.count('aeoui')`

Comment: @Engr.HasanuzzamanSumon Neat. Didn't know you could do that

Comment: I recently learn about refinements in Ruby, so instead of doing a really bad monkey patching you can limit it to small place in your code. http://timelessrepo.com/refinements-in-ruby

Comment: @Marc-Andre Yeah, I also just learned about them (like, just after posting this answer). Note though, that I'm not recommending monkey-patching, just illustrating the principle. And in any case, I wouldn't call this a "really bad monkey-patch"; it's fairly innocuous

Comment: @Flambino Yeah maybe "really bad monkey-patching" might be a bit dramatic ;), but anyway just wanted to still show something I found really cool about Ruby on the monkey-patching side. Like always really nice answer.

Comment: @Marc-Andre Thanks. And yeah, refinements are a very neat addition! Haven't had the chance to play around with them yet, unfortunately, but if nothing else it'll be nice to write reviews that illustrate monkey-patching without also warning against it :P

Comment: All these answers count total number of vowels rather than separate by vowel.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def count_vowels(string)
  vowels = { "a" => 0, "e" => 0, "i" => 0, "o" => 0, "u" => 0 }
  string.each_char { |char| vowels[char] += 1 if vowels.include?(char) }
  vowels
end
```

What did I change?

- Use two space indentation
- Don't abbr var nms, spell out `char`
- Use trailing `if` statement
- Use one-line loop with `{}` given the loop body is a single line now
- Omit `return`, the last statement is always returned

And if you want a oneliner try

```
vowels = string.scan(/[aeiou]/).group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:count)
```